# Issue of horizontal scrollview automatically scrolls on Edittext focus

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I am using `Horizontal Scroll View` containing `Relative Layout` with 6 `edittext` in it .All `edittext` are displayed horizontally in view

***MyXml.xml***

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/horizontalView">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >


        <!--android:weightSum="6"-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 android:id="@+id/sv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
             >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="hintvalue"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:ems="3"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sv1"
            android:id="@+id/sv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="hintvalue"
                    android:ems="4"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    android:maxLength="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sv2"
            android:id="@+id/sv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="hintvalue"
                    android:ems="4"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sv3"
            android:id="@+id/sv4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="hintvalue"
                    android:ems="3"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sv4"
            android:id="@+id/sv5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="hintvalue"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="1"

                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sv5"
            android:id="@+id/sv6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="hintvalue"
                    android:ems="5"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="3"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Question** : Now whenever I clicked on first `Edittext` (or any edittext). `horizontal scrollview` automatically scroll to the end position. I dont know about this behaviour. why horizontal scroll view  automatically scrolled?

***What I have tried***

1) I tried to call `smoothscroll` to 0,0 position on first edit text focus change.

```
 edt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                   hv1.smoothScrollTo(0,0)

                }
            }
        });
```

2) I also tried with creating one `custom class` extending `horizontal scrollview` and change postion to 0 in `onLayout` overrided method

```
public class HorizontalCustomScrollView extends android.widget.HorizontalScrollView {
    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public HorizontalCustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HorizontalCustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HorizontalCustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public HorizontalCustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
         this.scrollTo(0,0);  

    }

}
```

3) I also try to give direction to `fullScroll` to `FOCUS_LEFT` and also with `FOCUS_RIGHT` in `onLayout` overrided method but this is also not worked.

```
@Override
        protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
             //this.scrollTo(0,0);  

   this.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);

//and also try with Focus right

//this.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);


        }
```

***Before Focus***

[image]

***After Focus on Edit text 1 (or  2,3 or any other edittext .. Horizontal Scroll moves to last automatically.)***

[image]

But still Horizontal scroll view automatic scroll to last position . How can I make it stop?

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#requestfocus-element on first edittext

Comment: I am sorry @PetrovDmitrii . I dont understand. What I have to try? include it from antoher view or requestfocus tag? and also my question is not related to only one edittext but it is for all edittext . whichever edittext you clicked horizontal scrollview scrolls to end position.

Comment: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` Try to add this to relative layout.

Comment: tried already . it will just remove focus first time . but when you explicitly select edit text . HSV scrolled to end.@Beena

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am able to resolve my Problem here but still dont know why this is happening.

I remove all the properties of editext that are defined and added that all properties one by one and check which property causing issue and **I found out that when I add `gravity="center"` property to edittext again horizontal scroll view scrolls to end.**

**So It is happening because of  gravity="center" property of edittext.**

But still I don't know why gravity that is of edittext is direct affecting to horizontal scroll view weird behavior . is gravity is somehow related to content view of parent container ?

***If any one have answer about this behavior please share your views.***

Comment: Not only you there are many people including me who suffered from this **gravity="center"** issue. My `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` was working **only once** because of this..!!

Comment: oh that is strange. May be this is a bug of android or may be there is other thing that we are missing with this property. @jankigadhiya

Comment: possibly.. But for now we don't have any other solution. We can just stop using that..!!

Comment: yes I have to find other way to set font alignment to center for now. but have to check about this gravity issue also.

Comment: please let me know if you find any.. :)

Comment: I figure out actually gravity="center_horizontal" cause this problem. maybe it has a relationship with HorizontalScrollView. by the way thank you for your help.

Comment: I also figure out another thing. set `android:textAlignment="center"` has the same problem. so I'm sure these is a tiny invisible bug in horizontalScrollView :D